# Prevent multiple people from editing the same form

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I have a laravel app that is being used by multiple users at once, they all have the possibility to edit some projects in our system.

What I dont want is to have 2 people at the same time editing the same form.

**If that happens I would like to tell other users that the current form is locked and is being edited by username.**

If user then leaves or submits the form, then the form is opened for other users to work with.

**I have checked out both optimistic and pessimistic locking, I don't think this is correct for me**

What I was thinking of doing, was to create a unique identifier in the table, that is being edited, and if the user on the page has the identifier, I would lock all other out, but how would I know if the user closes the browser window? then all other users still can't access the page/form?

**How would you guys suggest I go about this?**

Comment: I'd create a table to keep temporary data relating the forms table. When user enters form id 1, I'd add the user id, form id, enter date and last modified date to the new table. I'd make an ajax request every 2 minutes or something, just to tell the server that I'm still working on the form, and update the table. If the user don't send anything for 5 minutes, or submit the form in this period of time, I'll remove the entry from the database. That way you can verify if someone is working on the form whenever you try to access it.

Comment: Hi @PhiterFernandes why whould you make a temporary data table?. i dont want anybody but one person at a time editing, so i was thinking of creating a vision number on access to the page for the first user, and if the user is done editing og closes the browser window, i whould delete the vision number. but how whould i know if the user has closed the browser window? Kind Regards / Dannie

Comment: CodeIgniter uses a ci_sessions table, which is used to store session data, temporarily. It's completely OK to do so, if it serves your purpose. With this extra table you can control multiple forms.

Comment: Oki @PhiterFernandes so if i understand you correctly, if the row with some userID and FormID exist in the temp table, i lock the form to other users, can you give an example how you whould delete the temp row if the user closes the browser window?

Comment: If he closes the browser window, you cannot know. You can make a routine or something that  will run every 5 minutes and verify if one of those records have expired. In the worst case, the form will be locked for 9:59 minutes without anyone using it.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes where whould you create this routine, whould you make it as a cron job, or just check each time somebody tries to access the same project.

Comment: Use Laravel Echo with its presence broadcasting. Here's the relevant Laracast video: https://laracasts.com/lessons/introducing-laravel-echo

Answer (score 5):

Add a nullable `locked_to` column to your `projects` database. Then in the `Project` model add this field to `$dates` array so it can be converted to `Carbon` instances automatically.

When someone opens the project for edit just set `locked_to` field to future date, i think +5 seconds may be a good choice. Edit form should send ajax request every 5 seconds to keep project locked for next 5 seconds.

When user saves project changes, locking will be stopped cause no ajax requests will be send. In that case you also have field which may tell you when the project was opened for the last time.

User won't be able to edit project if `locked_to` field is equal or greater than `new Carbon` instance.

**UPDATE - more info**

There is no need to clear this field. If user didn't finish editing - he just reloaded page, navigated to other page, closed window or browser, died etc... ajax for locking won't be executed anymore, so in the next 5 second currently edited project will be unlocked - `locked_to` field will contain earlier date than current.

Comment: Thanks @Piotr how whould you go about deleting the locked_to if the user leaves the page or closes the browser window?

Comment: Ahh so what you suggest is, user enters form i create locked_to field where the time is in the future, for each 5 second the user is on the page i send a ajax request that updates the locked_to in the future, if another user tries to access the page and the locked_to is not older then the current time, then the user cant access? correct :)

Comment: Hi @piotr i understand perfect :) i have added you on Linkedin do u have a mail i can write to, i have a webcompany in denmark and we look for developers? cut you be interrested ?

Comment: @piotr What if the the user keep open the Form without interaction ? I understand you can make the locked_to = false. So if you now let the other user allow to edit it the previous user will not have access. And do you think request in every 5 seconds will make pressure on server ?

Answer (score 0):

If the user keeps the page open put dead man switch prompt "are you still there", no user input will cause the page to stop the 5 second ajax refresh, thus allowing new users access.

If user returns the next day and clicks Yes, simply refresh the page, check if someone else doesn't already have it locked in and alert, alerting accordingly, but if not, restart the ajax 5 second timer.

Answer (score 0):

piotr's answer is almost perfect, the only issue (that I have found) arises when a user who is is locked out makes a request just before the current user editing the form. This can be mitigated by adding an extra bit of info to the lock, alongside the date, add the user id of the last person to lock it. Then every successful lock request should add a second more to the lock than the frequency of the requests, and the lock date should be updated every time the user id matched the id of the lock.