# SignalR, how to ensure that only one user can edit a given form at a time?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

I have a dashboard with a list of items and a finite number of users. I want to show "an item is being edited" near said item to avoid simultaneous edits and overwrites of data.
This seems to me like updating a flag in the database and relatively simple signalr implementation with the javascript simply adding/removing a css class.

I have seen this:
[Prevent multiple people from editing the same form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40962943/6019827)
which describes a method with posting every X minutes and clearing the flag from the database when there are no more update messages from the user.

The issue is:
I was wondering if there was a signalr method (like disconnect; i know it exists but I don't know if it fits this scenario) to do that elegantly rather than running a timer function. If so, is it possible for the server to miss the event and permanently leave the flagged as "editing" when it is not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could implement a hub for this, here is a example:

```
public class ItemAccessHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        // your logic to lock the object, set a state in the db

        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        // your logic to unlock the object

        return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

to get information from the query you can access the HttpContext:

```
Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Query.TryGetValue("item-id", out var itemId)
```

so you could start a connection when the user is accessing the form and send the id of the item in the query:

```
/hub/itemAccess?item-id=ITEM_ID
```

and when the user closes the form then disconnect the connection.
with this method the item is also unlocked when the user loses his network connection.

the on disconnect method is allays invoked when a client disconnects, so you can do your clean up in this method.

in this hub you can than also implement the update function

i hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: does this mean that it the disconnect method is always invoked even in "force cases" (like client computer crashed or process killed unexpectedly or electricity blackout)?

Comment: only if your server crashes it is not invoked. In the Documentation it says: "If a client application or the computer that it's running on crashes or goes to sleep [...] in these scenarios the server waits to give the client a chance to reconnect, and OnDisconnected does not execute until the disconnect timeout period expires (about 30 seconds by default)." [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#client-disconnection-scenarios)